# Vertically flatten multiple columns and merge based on multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe semble this:

```
   id city  2018  2019
0   1   bj   2.0   3.0
1   2   sh   3.0   3.5
2   3   gz   2.5   4.0
```

I need to vertically flatten column `2018` and `2019` to `year` and `price`, and then merge based on `id` and `city`.

The output I want is like this:

```
   id city  year  price
0   1   bj  2018    2.0
1   1   bj  2019    3.0
2   2   sh  2018    3.0
3   2   sh  2019    3.5
4   3   gz  2018    2.5
5   3   gz  2019    4.0
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: `df.melt(['id','city'],value_name='price').sort_values('id')`

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=['id', 'city'], 
        var_name="date", 
        value_name="price")`